# Micro service state is down on JHipster Registry v3.3.0

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud

I have a microservice and gateway generated with jhipster 5.0.1. Both are registred on the Jhipster Register version 3.3.0 with status **down**.
Did someone goes through this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

When a microservice is registering itself as down, it means the internal Healthchecks are stating something bad. This could be:

- your database is not reachable or other db related error
- some of your required spring dependencies are configured wrong, like RabbitMQ or something like that
- your space is low

Check the logs of the starting microservices, if there is any stacktrace or ERROR log appearing. If that doesn't work, you could checkout the health endpoints, as they give extra information on whats wrong.

Comment: I was my elasticsearch who was down.